# Use reflection to design an Event Aggregator?

Tags: .net, vb.net, event-handling

I am designing what I understand is an Event Aggregator: in my model I have an `IApplication` which has a collection of `IDocument`, which has a collection of `IWindow`. `IWindow` exposes events such as `AfterActivate`, or `MouseUp`, etc. I want to be able to listen to these events from either the `IDocument`, or the `IApplication`. I am looking for an object which takes a list of the `IWindow` it must listen to, and mimics the `IWindow` events.

This should allow `IApplication` to:

1. create the aggregator,
2. give it a collection of `IWindows` to listen to, and
3. allow `IApplication` to only subscribe to the aggregator.

Then, when one `IWindow` raises an event X, it will trigger `IAggregator`, which itself will raise an event X, which will be handled by `IApplication`.

I have started with the code provided below. In principle it works, but in this example the aggregator propagates only 2 events. In reality, I have much more: there are several aggregators (one for the `IApplication`, and also one per `IDocument`), which work on many different objects, not just `IWindow`. I would be keen to be able to get rid of all this duplicate code. Note that I do not want my aggregator to expose composite events from the combination of several objects being listened to: each aggregator listen to only one type of object and exposes the events which are exposed by this type.

Is there a way to replicate this mechanism at run time rather than design, maybe by taking advantage of reflection? I also sense that a generic procedure could be useful, but I am yet to find how to take advantage of this. More than anything, I would like to know if well-thought solutions already existed so that I do not re-invent the wheel.

```
Public Class WindowEventsAggregator
    Implements IWindowEvents


    Private WithEvents _WindowsToObserve As ObservableCollection(Of IWindowEvents)

    Private Property WindowsCurrentlyObserved As List(Of IWindowEvents)


    Sub New(windowsToObserve As ObservableCollection(Of IWindowEvents))
        Me._WindowsToObserve = windowsToObserve
        Me.WindowsCurrentlyObserved = New List(Of IWindowEvents)
    End Sub


    Private Sub _WindowsToObserve_CollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) Handles _WindowsToObserve.CollectionChanged

        SyncLock _Lock

            Dim WindowsToObserve_LocalCopy As IReadOnlyCollection(Of IWindowEvents) = _WindowsToObserve.ToList

            For Each Win As IWindowEvents In WindowsCurrentlyObserved
                RemoveHandler Win.AfterActivate, AddressOf AfterActivateEventHandler
                RemoveHandler Win.AfterDeactivate, AddressOf AfterDeactivateEventHandler
            Next

            WindowsCurrentlyObserved.Clear()

            For Each Win As IWindowEvents In WindowsToObserve_LocalCopy
                AddHandler Win.AfterActivate, AddressOf AfterActivateEventHandler
                AddHandler Win.AfterDeactivate, AddressOf AfterDeactivateEventHandler
            Next

            WindowsCurrentlyObserved = WindowsToObserve_LocalCopy.ToList

        End SyncLock

    End Sub
    Private _Lock As Object


    #Region "IWindowEvents"


    Public Event AfterActivate(window As IWindow) Implements IWindowEvents.AfterActivate

    Public Event AfterDeactivate(window As IWindow) Implements IWindowEvents.AfterDeactivate


    Private Sub AfterActivateEventHandler(window As IWindow)
        RaiseEvent AfterActivate(window)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AfterDeactivateEventHandler(window As IWindow)
        RaiseEvent AfterDeactivate(window)
    End Sub


    #End Region


End Class
```

Comment: Are you already using any third-party libraries for this functionality?

Comment: @Craig no, the entire code is shown here. Could you suggest any?

Comment: I was asking partly because it looks a lot like what you might expect with the Microsoft Prism libraries (Microsoft.Practices.Composite, Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation, Microsoft.Practices.Unity, etc).  I can't give a comparative recommendation (and it would be somewhat off-topic for SO as an opinion anyway), but I can say that it seems to have some of the things you're looking for.

Comment: ok thanks, my post may be better placed into Code Review; I am considering moving it over there.

Comment: @Craig I found an [Event Aggregator](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/event-aggregator.html) in the Prism Library, which is exactly what I was looking for. So the way to go is to not rely upon the native event system of VB/C#, but rather implement the Observer pattern with strongly typed events. Not sure I will add a dependency to Prism just for this, but it provides sufficient structure to mimic and quickly make my own implementation of it.